# How to disable custom keyboard fullscreen?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Im trying to make **custom keyboard**. When use it, **keyboard always make fullscreen mode**, but when use system keyboard everythink is okay. Does anyone know how to fix it?
For better undestanding im including images.

**Current State:**

1- My keyboard
[image: My keyboard]
2- System keyboard
[image: System keyboard]

**How it have to looks.**

3 - What i want (not a screenshot - edited in paint)
[image: Thats what i want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code in InputMethodService should solve your problem:

```
@Override
public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some  ways in which you can disable this full screen keyboard in Landscape mode,

```
 @Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {

    outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;


}
```

or

add following line in the `EditText` in xml,

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

or

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

Comment: It works fine. But when i have more field for input, or make this no fullscreen mode globally, is better solution from @KarolGasienica. Thank you very much! :)